# Creating a scraper that isolates a part of a page, and then scrapes the title and first paragraph from every link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def custom_scrape(e1, master):
session = requests.Session()
# selectWikiPage = input("Please enter the Wikipedia page you wish to scrape from")
selectWikiPage = e1.get()
if "wikipedia" in selectWikiPage: #turn this into a regular expression
    html = session.post(selectWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    findReferences = bsObj.find('ol', {'class': 'references'})  # isolate refereces section of page
    href = BeautifulSoup(str(findReferences), "html.parser")
    links = [a["href"] for a in href.find_all("a", href=True)]
    for link in links:
        print("Link: " + link)
else:
    print("Error: Please enter a valid Wikipedia URL")
```

As you can see, I am able to isolate the references section of the Wikipedia page, but I am unsure as how to make it enter the isolated links, and then carry out the actions aforementioned in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium driver to simulate click on those links.

```
<body>
<a href="hello.html"   target="_self">Hello</a>
</body>
```

To click on link hello.html do like this

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Details')
link.click()
```